# winForms + DataGridView binding to a List<T> (Visual Studio 2005, C# 2.0)

Tags: datagridview, c#-2.0

I have the following code but the DatGridView is showing me empty rows. I can't find the solution. I have set the `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`. If I set it to `true`, it creates the rows, but I'm not allowed to set this property to `true` (client wish).

What am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<AStruct> _aCollectionList;
    private BindingList<AStruct> _aCollectionBindingList;

    public struct AStruct
    {
        public string ACode
        {
            get { return _aCode; }
            set { _aCode = value; }
        }

        public string AName
        {
            get { return _aName; }
            set { _aName = value; }
        }

        private string _aCode;
        private string _aName;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _aCollectionList = new List<AStruct>();
        FillCollectionStruct(true);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = _aList;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();            
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        _aCollectionBindingList = new BindingList<AStruct>();
        FillCollectionStruct(false);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _aBindingList;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();         
    }

    private void FillCollectionStruct(bool listBool)
    {
        AStruct aStruct = new AStruct();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            aStruct.ACode = i.ToString();
            aStruct.AName = i.ToString();

            if (listBool)
                _aCollectionList.Add(aStruct);
            else
                _aCollectionBindingList.Add(aStruct);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Form1.Designer I do make the following columns:

```cs
// 
// aCodeColumn
// 
this.colorCodeColumn.DataPropertyName = "Code";
this.colorCodeColumn.HeaderText = "a code";
this.colorCodeColumn.Name = "aCodeColumn";
// 
// aNameColumn
// 
this.colorNameColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
this.colorNameColumn.HeaderText = "a name";
this.colorNameColumn.Name = "aNameColumn";
```

Comment: why the client doesn't want to see Autogenerated rows? Those are the data. He doesn't want to see the data ?

Comment: In the columns that are already present:

Comment: SO in the following columns: // 
        // aCodeColumn
        // 
        this.colorCodeColumn.DataPropertyName = "Code";
        this.colorCodeColumn.HeaderText = "a code";
        this.colorCodeColumn.Name = "aCodeColumn";
        // 
        // aNameColumn
        // 
        this.colorNameColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
        this.colorNameColumn.HeaderText = "a name";
        this.colorNameColumn.Name = "aNameColumn";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just change the bindings from:

```cs
// aCodeColumn
// 
this.colorCodeColumn.DataPropertyName = "Code";
this.colorCodeColumn.HeaderText = "a code";
this.colorCodeColumn.Name = "aCodeColumn";
// 
// aNameColumn
// 
this.colorNameColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
this.colorNameColumn.HeaderText = "a name";
this.colorNameColumn.Name = "aNameColumn";
```

To:

```cs
// aCodeColumn
// 
this.colorCodeColumn.DataPropertyName = "ACode";
this.colorCodeColumn.HeaderText = "a code";
this.colorCodeColumn.Name = "aCodeColumn";
// 
// aNameColumn
// 
this.colorNameColumn.DataPropertyName = "AName";
this.colorNameColumn.HeaderText = "a name";
this.colorNameColumn.Name = "aNameColumn";
```

Shouldn't that work?

Since the `DataPropertyName` is what binds to your properties the names have to be the same, else there's no way for the compiler to know what goes where.

Comment: This solves the problem, the DataPropertyName wasn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem write you could use sth like this.dataGridView1.Refresh(); in order to repopulate it and before the line you refresh put this.dataGridView1.DataSource = _aCollectionBindingList;

Comment: OK, the problem here was that the "DataPropertyName" of the DataGridView wasn't set right. By giving this the right name it works.
Thnx all for your answers.